# A person who chooses one of two opposing sides of an issue

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any single word for a person who chooses one of two opposing sides of an issue?

Comment: So you're looking for somebody who does **not** _sit on the fence_?

Comment: Can you please provide some context where you are looking to use the requested word?

Comment: To everybody: Can the word/phrase `dual personality` or `split personality` be used in this case?

Comment: @KK: Definitely not. It could be used (wrongly in medical terms, and certainly insultingly) for somebody who supported both sides of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

*Proponent*, perhaps. That, in the OED’s definition, is

> a person who puts forward or advocates a theory, proposal, or course
>   of action; a propounder, a proposer. In later use also more generally:
>   a person who is in favour of a proposal, a supporter.

Alternatively, you might want to consider *protagonist*. A protagonist originally meant the main character in a play or other work of fiction, but its use is now extended to describe someone who promotes, advocates or defends a particular cause or idea.

Comment: However you can be a proponent for one issue without the existence of an opposing issue

Answer (score 2):

**Advocate**

If the discussion was cheese board or ice cream, in the great "what shall we have for pudding" debate, then I would always be a cheese board **advocate**.

My daughter would be an ice cream **advocate**.

Comment: That is only if you decide that there are two issues. I can be an advocate on one issue without a second issue.

Answer (score 0):

**[Bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias)**

The person is biased or shows bias

> **Noun**
>   Prejudice in favor of or against one thing, person, or group compared with another, usually in a way considered to be unfair.
>
> **Verb**
>   Show prejudice for or against (someone or something) unfairly: "the tests were biased against women"; "a biased view of the world".
>
> **Synonyms**
>   noun.   prejudice - inclination - partiality - tendency
>   verb.   influence - prejudice

---

**[Partial to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/partial+to)** - idiom - more than two things may exist to partial to

---

**[Take sides](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+sides)** - an idiom - more than two sides may exist to choose from

---

**One-sided** or **Slanted** - again slightly negative antonyms to *impartial*

---

**[Partisan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partisan_%28political%29)**

> In politics, a partisan is a committed member of a political party. In multi-party systems, the term is widely understood to carry a negative connotation - referring to those who wholly support their party's policies and are perhaps even reluctant to acknowledge correctness on the part of their political opponents in almost any situation.

---

Whereas *proponent* and *advocate* can be for one thing only, the above examples are relevant for two (Bias) respectively two or more issues (partial to ,take sides, partisan)

Comment: A partisan, by definition, is throwing their lot in with a group and acting for the group on all issues, rather than choosing a side on a given issue. If e.g. someone opposed to the death penalty was in a party that supported it, then they'd be **more** partisan in ignoring the issue, **less** partisan in promoting their own views, against the party line.

Comment: Both your suggestions imply irrational behavior. If you are biased or partisan, you are not picking a side logically, you are picking it because of external factors not related to the issue. People who are biased or partisan can choose one side of an argument, but not all people who choose one side of an argument are biased or partisan.

Comment: I would not necessarily call it irrational to be biased towards some issue. How about Partial to?

Comment: What's with the down-vote? Biased is the word to use if the meaning is a negative one. That does not mean it is wrong!

Comment: I did think a bit before using the word irrational. I couldn't think of a better (or less worse) word to use though.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers Partisan certainly doesn't imply irrational; it can be used to imply that you are *just* going with the party line, but it doesn't insist upon that on its own, and nor is that necessarily irrational. Bias likewise can suggest a lack of full critical thinking, but doesn't entail it, and doesn't imply that said lack of critical thinking is irrational (e.g. if I'm biased due to a genuine concern about related matters, that's both fair and rational, and if I'm biased because I'll get a lot more money personally with one option, that's unfair but still rational).

Comment: I mean irrational in the sense that you may be voting for something you don't actually agree with. On a side note, I do find it irrational that this thread was closed because it wasn't deemed a proper question, when it got 3 proper answers.

Comment: I agree. I often get baffled when questions get closed

Answer (score 0):

Perheps *[defender](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/defender)*

> a person who supports another person or thing in the face of criticism, esp by argument or evidence:
>    *-a strong defender of human rights;
>
>   -they were staunch defenders of democracy;
>
>   -the most ardent defenders of conventional family values*